# Reuse UITextField value to control arc length of gauge

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ibaction

I'm creating 3 semi-circular gauges containing a UITextField each.

I have created separate swift files (with their own classes of UIView) for each gauge where I programatically design the look of the arcs making up the gauge (segment lines etc). One of these arcs acts like a pointer, showing anywhere from empty to full (`startAngle` which is 149° to `endAngle` which is 31°). I'm using `@IBOutlet` to access the field values (declaring it `main1Field`), but I have to use CGFloat and I can't figure out how to declare a constant where the values can be used in the function.

Q1: What is the way to convert whatever is in the `UITextField` to values that can be calculated in my function?

Q2: I wan't the `main1Field` inputs to directly draw the arc. I was hoping to use `@IBAction` as you can see so that the arc is drawn live as the user enters a number into the field. The way I do it doesn't work however.

```
@IBAction func main1arc(_ sender: UITextField) { //THIS DOESN'T WORK

    func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

        //Arc
        let fullTank = 3920
        let main1Fuel = CGFloat(self.main1Field) //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        let startAngle = (149 * CGFloat.pi) / 180
        let endAngle = (31 * CGFloat.pi) / 180
        let angleDifference: CGFloat = 2 * .pi - startAngle + endAngle
        let arcLength = angleDifference / CGFloat(fullTank)
        let arcEnd = arcLength * CGFloat(main1Fuel) + startAngle
        let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                               radius: radius / 2 - Constants.arcWidth / 2,
                               startAngle: startAngle,
                               endAngle: arcEnd,
                               clockwise: true)
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Edited to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You can use UITextFieldDelegate method [shouldChangeCharactersInRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) or [target action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) to be notified of changes in your textField.
2. When there is a change, convert your textField.text value into a **Double**, then convert the **Double** into a **CGFloat**.  (**CGFloat** has no string initializer).

Example with target action **.editingChanged**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let textField = UITextField()
    let label = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let stack = UIStackView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 60))
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .gray
        stack.addArrangedSubview(textField)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        view.addSubview(stack)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(edit), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc private func edit() {
        guard let floatValue = textField.text.flatMap({Double($0)}).map({CGFloat($0)}) else {
            label.text = "Not a valid CGFloat"
            return
        }
        label.text = "Valid float value: \(floatValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so you mean I should add `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` and `textField.addTarget(self, action:`... in the ViewController file. Will `@IBAction` work in my separate swift file for the arc class then? How come `@IBAction` doesn't work on its own? I've used it without problems like that elsewhere...

Comment: Target action should work with IBAction but you need to right click and drag from . editingChanged. I did this in a playground though, so there was no interface builder.

Comment: Still don't get it to work. I have added `main1Field.addTarget(self, action: #selector(????), for: editingChanged)` in the `viewDidLoad()` after the self delegates in ViewController.swift. In my Main1.swift file I have the `@IBAction` code from my question above. Now since the `@IBAction` is in another swift file with the `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)`function that creates the arc, what do I write inside `#selector()` in your addTarget solution? I have tried typing `#selector(main1Arc.draw(_:)` since the class in Main1.swift is called main1Arc but this doesn't seem to be correct.